# Stopping windows workflow activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Actually i was working on an application which is using the Windows workflow foundation (State Machine Workflow) , Initially we were getting the Error "Workflow with ID ""XXXX" not found in the state persitance store and we found the root cause , this was due to the reason our workflow was getting completed but it should not get completed for the particular cases.

How to stop the Windows Workflow foundation with some conditions

Answer (score 0):

Use [TerminateWorkflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.terminateworkflow.aspx) activity.